# Dependency Injection in Angular2 - TypeScript syntax vs @Inject

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using [Angular2 build 2.0.0-alpha.34](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha34-2015-08-07) and I'm not sure why these two different pieces of code are giving me different results.

The only difference is using `@Inject(TitleService) titleService` vs using `titleService: TitleService`

This correctly works (ES2015 way)

```
import {Inject, Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {titleComponent} from './components/title';
import {TitleService} from './services/services';

// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: './html/app.html',
    directives: [titleComponent, NgFor]
})
// Component controller
class MyAppComponent {
    titles: Array<Object>;
    constructor(@Inject(TitleService) titleService) {
        console.log(titleService)
        this.titles = titleService.getTitles();
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent,[TitleService]);
```

This doesn't work (TypeScript way), it doesn't ever make it to the `console.log` call in constructor, but it doesn't throw an error

```
import {Inject, Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {titleComponent} from './components/title';
import {TitleService} from './services/services';

// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: './html/app.html',
    directives: [titleComponent, NgFor]
})
// Component controller
class MyAppComponent {
    titles: Array<Object>;
    constructor(titleService: TitleService) {
        console.log(titleService)
        this.titles = titleService.getTitles();
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent,[TitleService]);
```

If I'm using TypeScript's way to inject, do I need to do something else somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had TitleService defined in a JavaScript file, using an ES2015 class, I just needed to change it to a TypeScript file so it compiled correctly. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it in the viewBindings of your Component annotation :

```
viewBindings: [TitleService]
```

Note that you only need to do it once, say in the Root component and every other component within the hierarchy will get it injecting from the root component, as if the component's injector can't resolve the dependency it goes up until it finds it. If you define one viewBindings you should have the same instance everywhere I believe.

edit: renaming of parameter in alpha 34.

Comment: The OP is injecting the service through `bootstrap(MyAppComponent,[TitleService])`, so I think it should work. Also `viewInjector` became `viewBindings` in alpha-34.

Comment: @AnotherDev Two more things, viewInjector has been renamed bindings, and have you check that you declare your TitleService as Injectable ? I just did a check on a local project and just using the bindings property without bootstrapping the service, and it worked fine. But your code above should work at a first glance, do you get any error ?

Comment: No error. If I use `viewBindings`, I get the same problem. It works with @Inject, but not with TypeScript. How do I declare TitleService as Injectable? Right now it's just defined as a class

Comment: you need to use the @Injectable decorator. And you can see here in the parameters of the constructor : [documentation for ComponentAnnotation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/annotations/ComponentAnnotation-class.html). So you have viewBindings, and bindings for the old viewInjector and appInjector. I did a test last night again and it worked fine with the bindings parameter.